# How to inject dependencies into a WPF Window class with StructureMap?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm trying to use StructureMap to inject dependencies into my WPF Window constructors.

A sample of the code I have is:

```
public partial class PanelConfiguration : Window
{
    private IPanelConfigurationService _panelConfiguration; 

    public PanelConfiguration(IPanelConfigurationService panelConfiguration)
    {
        _panelConfiguration = panelConfiguration;
    }
}
```

And I have ObjectFactory configured as

```
// I was hoping the following would inject the interface into the constructor for me
For<PanelConfiguration>()
    .Use<PanelConfiguration>()
    .Ctor<IPanelConfigurationService>().Is<PanelConfigurationService>();

For<IPanelConfigurationRepository>()
        .Use<PanelConfigurationRepository>()
        .Ctor<string>("qFile").Is(config.QDefault);

For<IPanelConfigurationService>()
    .Use<PanelConfigurationService>();
```

What do I need to do to inject the depenedencies into the Window classes as I need?

Comment: Have you tried simply resolving the PanelConfiguration window from StructureMap?

Comment: Hi @DavidNelson, I'm not sure what you mean? Could you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: I mean get an instance of PanelConfiguration from StructureMap the same way you would get an instance of any other configured type. I'm not familiar with StructureMap, but all DI frameworks have some equivalent of "context.Resolve<PanelConfiguration>();"

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I was confounded by a PEBKAC error. I've resolved it :)